# when cast pointer to point to a struct containing union

Tags: c, pointers, casting, struct, unions

I have problem with a struct containing union. Here is the problem:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char Type;                          
    union
    {
        unsigned char Length;
        unsigned __int16 Length2;
    }
    char Value[0];    
} TLV_TUPLE, *PTLV_TUPLE;
```

If `Type == 0x40h`, I use `Length2`, otherwise use `Length`.

I use this structure to read this file stream (In hex):

`FE 01 01 40 12 00 30 …`

Now the code:

```
unsigned char * m_pTLV;

/*code here to  let m_pTLV points to the
  first byte of the file, that is, point to 'FE' */

PTLV_TUPLE pTlv = (PTLV_TUPLE)m_pTLV; // cast m_pTLV to PTLV_TUPLE
```

Then as I check the value of pTlv with debugger, I see this:

```
pTlv->Type == FE
pTlv->Length == 1
pTlv->Length2 == 4001
pTlv->Value == 12
```

Shouldn't `Length2` be `0x101` and `value` be `48`?

machine is little endian.

Please help me with this...

Comment: Reading a `struct` directly from a file is almost always a bad idea. Write (or even better generate) your serialization code working member by member.

Comment: @6502, you're probably right for data that will need to be used elsewhere but, for data that will only ever be used in that single program, a single read/write is (IMNSHO) preferable than all the effort involved in serialising individual elements. The data file may need migration if padding or other formats ever change but I'd prefer to expend that effort when/if it's needed.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is that the structure is being padded with an extra byte so that the union can be correctly aligned.

The `01` following the `FE` is padding, the actual union starts at the next byte. That's because the alignment requirement for a union is affected by the alignment requirements of its parts.

Since `Length2` has a requirement to be aligned on a two-byte boundary, a padding byte is inserted before it to ensure this happens.

If the stream you read in was `FE FF 01 40 12 00 30 ...`, you would still get the same values.

---

As an aside, I think `"Shouldn’t Length2 be 0101 and value be 48?"` should actually have read `64 (0x40)` rather than `48 (0x30)`. I assume that was a typo on your part.

---

If you *need* the structure to not have padding, there's no *standard* way to do it but your compiler should provide a way. For example, you could use something like attributes in `gcc`:

```
typedef  struct {
    unsigned char Type;                          
    union {
        unsigned char Length;
        unsigned __int16 Length2;
    }
    char Value[0];    
} __attribute__ ((aligned(1),packed)) TLV_TUPLE;
```

Other environments may provide a `#pragma pack` or something similar to acheive the same end.